# Delete Files with mac terminal

Tags: regex, macos, terminal

I'm trying to use find in the terminal to delete some files that PyCharm has created seemingly at random. It's created duplicates of files like:

```
manage.py
manage 2.py
manage 3.py
index.js
index 2.js
```

So the pattern I'm trying to match is a string followed by a space and then a number with different endings. Currently I'm trying:

```
find pathToMyFiles -type -f -regex '.+?\w+ [0-9](.py|.js)$'
```

This fails to identify any files in the directory even though it captures my test strings when I go to regexer or any of the other regex test sites, am I missing something that's mac terminal exclusive? I know this script will not delete any files, I'm just trying to make sure I'm correctly identifying them first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of regular expressions, you could combine two `-name` statements:

```
$ find -name '* [[:digit:]].py' -o -name '* [[:digit:]].js'
./manage 2.py
./manage 3.py
./index 2.js
```

This finds anything that ends in a blank and a digit with extension `.py` or `.js`.

If you want to use your regex, you have to escape a few things differently (see [default regular expression syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#findutils_002ddefault-regular-expression-syntax)):

```
$ find -regex '.+\w+ [0-9]\.\(py\|js\)$'
./manage 2.py
./manage 3.py
./index 2.js
```

`()` for capture groups, `|` for alternation and `.` for literal period all have to be escaped. `.+?` is not a valid combination.

Comment: The name statements worked like a charm. How would you go about deleting the files? Just -delete or -exec rm {} \; ?

Comment: @MichaelPorter `-delete` works if you use GNU find; otherwise, `-exec rm {} \;` should be fine (or `-exec rm {} +` to call `rm` just once).